# How can I put a picture frame on the floor

Tags: framing, frame

I'm putting some picture frames in a photographer's studio. I will hang some of these frames in the wall, but I would like to have some of these on the floor, this way:
[image: some picture frames in the floor]

The problem is: there's some wind circulating in there, and the frames keep falling. I also want to be able to move them around, so I'm not fixing their tops to the wall.

What are some nice ways to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get a roll of self adhesive Velcro. Put a horizontal stripe on the wall and then a small piece on the back of the picture. When you want to move pull out slide over and restick.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I want to be able to move the frames away from this wall so I can use this white empty wall as a background for some photos. I didn't say it in the main question,sorry. But this makes impossible to use Velcro :(

Comment: Well,
My wife changed her mind, decided a little white velcro wouldn't be a problem, and turns out this was a great solution.

No frame has fallen for the past weeks. We used some small 3m white velcros.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding weights to the back of the frames? That would stop them from blowing over due to their lightness.

Answer (score 0):

As Demi pointed out above, I would try to add weights to the inside of the frames of your artwork. You could go to a major hardware store and purchase metal rods and use a heat glue gun to attach them to the inside of the frame. What I would do is buy a type of rod that can be glued on the inside along the wooden frame but only glue them on the bottom and possibly the lower half or entire length of the inner sides. I would not glue one on the top inside of the frame. You want to make them "bottom" heavy so that they don't have too much top weight to fall over.

You might be able to find some rods at the length you need or you can buy longer ones and cut them down to size with a hacksaw. Good luck!